# How To Disable System Updates On Motorola Moto G Stylus 5G? Or How To Disable System App With ADB (Package Is Protected/Protected Package)?

Tags: adb, updates, ota-update, system

I have a Cricket branded Motorola Moto G 5G Stylus running Android 11, and I'm trying to disable the system updates. I've already disabled system updates in developer options, but it still forces updates - I can delay the update for ONE day, and then it forces the update with absolutely no way to stop it, and no more delays. You get 24 hours and then it forces it.

I tried using ADB to directly disable the system update apps. There are two, both labeled "Cricket Software Update" with package names com.motorola.android.fota and com.motorola.ccc.ota. I disabled com.motorola.android.fota, but when I try to disable, uninstall, or clear com.motorola.ccc.ota, ADB gives an error "Cannot disable a protected package" or "Failure: package is protected."

I use this phone for reliability testing, and forced restarts for system updates break that. Not to mention the updates themselves often break functionality of other apps or system features. I don't need updates, don't want updates, so how do I disable system updates on my Motorola Moto G Stylus 5G? Or, how can I disable protected system packages/apps with ADB?

Comment: Do you have the ability to unlock the bootloader and root the device? That is about the only way on modern Android devices like this unfortunately. Last time I checked, Moto (Lenovo) eliminated the ability to unlock the bootloader back in like 2018 though.

Comment: You could try to use a VPN based ad-blocker (like Blokada) that allows you to define custom block lists. If you could find out the network names used in the update check process you could block them. Without a working network connection to the update servers the update checker will not work and no new updates will be downloaded.